Does REORGANIZE compact pages and respect fill factor?
I've always been told that REORGANIZE does nothing to fix poor page fullness because all that it does is reorder pages on disk. To investigate this, I read the documentation. However, I've found it contradicting itself. Optimize index maintenance to improve query performance and reduce resource consumption claims

Reorganizing also compacts index pages to make page density equal to the fill factor of the index.

and the docs for ALTER INDEX support this

Reorganizing also compacts the index pages. Compaction is based on the existing fill factor value.

but this is contradicted by the documentation for fill factor

An explicit FILLFACTOR setting applies only when the index is first created or rebuilt. The Database Engine doesn't dynamically keep the specified percentage of empty space in the pages.

So, what's going on? Does REORGANIZE compact pages and respect fill factor? Or is it just moving leaf pages and not compacting?

Did you try it? These things are very easy to try, and you don't have to take somebody else's word for it.
Show answer is:
Yes. Reorg does compact pages.
See below code, where there's a clustered index with about 68% fullness at leaf level and after reorg it is 99%.
Regarding below statement in the documentation:

An explicit FILLFACTOR setting applies only when the index is first
created or rebuilt. The Database Engine doesn't dynamically keep the
specified percentage of empty space in the pages.

Above refers to general modification statements. (It would be ridiculous to maintain fillfactor when you do an insert, for instance.) Why isn't reorg mention in the exception list? Evidently an oversight. You are welcome to do documentation feedback, if you feel like it.
The repro:
USE tempdb
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS frag
CREATE TABLE frag(c1 int identity, c2 varchar(80))
GO

--Clustered index on c1 column
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX c1 ON frag(c1)

--Insert 100,000 rows
INSERT INTO frag (c2) 
SELECT TOP 100000 'Hello' FROM sys.columns AS a CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS b CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c
GO

--Generate fragmentation, make half of the rows larger
UPDATE frag SET c2 = 'Hello there, everybody!'  WHERE c1 % 2 = 1
GO

--Verify page fullness: 68% 
SELECT page_count, avg_page_space_used_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('frag'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
WHERE index_level = 0


--Reorg
ALTER INDEX ALL ON frag REORGANIZE


--Check page fullness: 99% 
SELECT page_count, avg_page_space_used_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('frag'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
WHERE index_level = 0

